# Trusty on SD card under Crouton - corrupted disk?

Tags: 14.04, apt, dpkg, sd-card, crouton

This question relates to Crouton only in that Ubuntu is running under it on my Chromebook. I've installed 14.04 with xfce on an ext4-formatted SD card.

I seem to be having all kinds of problems, and no packages seem to want to install correctly. One of the packages I tried to install was Firefox, which would not install correctly through Software Center despite running it as `gksu software-center` per [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/253607/399164). In attempting to install it from the command line, I get this input/output error (sorry for the long paste):

```
Preparing to unpack .../firefox_37.0.1+build1-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking firefox (37.0.1+build1-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) over (37.0.1+build1-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/firefox_37.0.1+build1-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 unable to create `/etc/apport/native-origins.d/firefox.dpkg-new' (while processing `./etc/apport/native-origins.d/firefox'): Input/output error
/bin/df: '/mnt/stateful_partition': No such file or directory
                                                             /bin/df: '/usr/share/oem': No such file or directory
                                 /bin/df: '/home/chronos': No such file or directory
    /bin/df: '/home/.shadow/472855b8f1a7fba3c1a1f1160e3f4f39f8236d43/mount': No such file or directory
                      /bin/df: '/home/chronos/user': No such file or directory
                                                                              /bin/df: '/home/user/472855b8f1a7fba3c1a1f1160e3f4f39f8236d43': No such file or directory
       /bin/df: '/home/chronos/u-472855b8f1a7fba3c1a1f1160e3f4f39f8236d43': No such file or directory
                     /bin/df: '/home/root/472855b8f1a7fba3c1a1f1160e3f4f39f8236d43': No such file or directory
                              /bin/df: '/run/crw': No such file or directory
                                                                            Selecting previously unselected package xul-ext-ubufox.
Preparing to unpack .../xul-ext-ubufox_3.0-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking xul-ext-ubufox (3.0-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1.1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/firefox_37.0.1+build1-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
(trusty)james@localhost:~$ dmesg | tail -30
[10563.225680] EXT4-fs error (device sdb1): ext4_mb_generate_buddy:742: group 464, 22958 clusters in bitmap, 22957 in gd
    (...plus ~25 more of that error...)
[10563.247003] EXT4-fs error (device sdb1): ext4_find_dest_de:1645: inode #133094: block 532849: comm dpkg: bad entry in directory: rec_len is smaller than minimal - offset=0(0), inode=0, rec_len=0, name_len=0
[10563.248966] ecryptfs_do_create: Failure to create dentry in lower fs; rc = [-5]
[10563.248979] ecryptfs_create: Failed to create file inlower filesystem
[10564.825928] EXT4-fs error (device sdb1): ext4_mb_generate_buddy:742: group 16, 24208 clusters in bitmap, 24197 in gd
[10567.444090] EXT4-fs error (device sdb1): ext4_mb_generate_buddy:742: group 387, 17420 clusters in bitmap, 18620 in gd
(trusty)james@localhost:~$
```

The output at the bottom from `dmesg` was per [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/97622), and indicates that there are certainly some file IO errors. `sdb` is my SD card.

My question is this: Does this problem seem related to my installation being on an SD card? If it is a problem with the file IO, it might also help explain the problems I'm having with other packages such as `dpkg: error: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/available' near line 0:` from a corrupt file (full of garbage), and `files list file for package '(package name)' is missing final newline`, to name a couple. Would installing Trusty directly on my SSD potentially help with these problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update, ~10 days later: I reinstalled Trusty directly on my Chromebook's internal SSD under Crouton, and have had no problems since. I believe the issues above were related to an issue with Crouton resuming after the computer has gone to sleep (see [issue #288](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton/issues/288)). It also may have been caused by accidentally removing the SD card without properly ejecting it.

Comment: I used this app and it helped: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/keep-awake/bijihlabcfdnabacffofojgmehjdielb?hl=en